# How to Remove a array elements in angularJS like jQuery RemoveAll()?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a problem when loading a call. Before that I need to clear the array. I am using `angularJS`.

```
 $scope.Load = function ()
 {
    $scope.StudentDetails = [];
    $http({ method: 'GET', url: '/Home/GetStudentDetails' }).success(function (data)
    {
        if (data != null)
        {
            $.each(data.Data, function (index, value)
            {
                $scope.StudentDetails.push(value);
            });

           // $scope.checked = false;
        }
    }).error(function ()
    {
        alert("Failed");
    });
}
```

Here `$scope.StudentDetails` is my array every time I load the data. Data will append, not clearing the data before load.

Comment: Have you tried using angular.forEach instead of $.each ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

actually , you can clear a array by splice

```
var a = [1,2,3]
a.splice(0,3) // now a is an empty array
```

or simply `a.splice(0)` will work.

if you did it with `a = []`, it will actually create a new empty array, and the angular's two-way bindings will fail for some scenarios, since it's suddenly not the same array.

Answer (score 0):

Clear array before pushing values. I think this code will solve your problem:

```
$scope.Load = function ()
 {
    $scope.StudentDetails = [];
    $http({ method: 'GET', url: '/Home/GetStudentDetails' }).success(function (data)
    {
        if (data != null)
        {
            $scope.StudentDetails = [];
            $.each(data.Data, function (index, value)
            {
                $scope.StudentDetails.push(value);
            });

           // $scope.checked = false;
        }
    }).error(function ()
    {
        alert("Failed");
    });
}
```

Comment: Both codes are same..i am using this code also ..but cant get the exact .

Comment: @Sankar, ` $scope.StudentDetails = [];`

Comment: @Satpal Sir is there any function to remove Data from the array like jQuery array.removeAll()

Comment: @Sankar, Try `$scope.StudentDetails.length = 0;`

Comment: Sir instantly this working .But i need exact solution.If u have an idea please share with me sir..

Comment: @Sankar, This is the solution and quite fast